# Create MVC in Visual Studio using Material Design

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015, material-design, nuget-package

I want to create one project in Visual studio which use material design for its default User Interface. What are the steps that I have to follow to make this project.

What I have done is:

1. Created project
     i. using asp.net web application
     ii. using asp.net 4.5.2 MVC template
2. Installed MaterialSkin using Nuget Package Manager.

Now what I want is I want next other steps from here to completely install Material design.

I have my solution explorer image:

[image]

Comment: @pooriataghizadeh, care to explain?

Comment: @dexter, were you able to proceed with this?